# Help finding an article

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, commutative-algebra, lie-algebras

Hello Recently I have been studying algebra and am in search of the following paper :

Kac, V. G. Classification of simple $Z$-graded Lie superalgebras and simple Jordan superalgebras. Comm. Algebra 5 (1977), no. 13, 1375–1400.

If somebody can help me with a data base free link or sending me the paper I will be happy because I currently have access to one data base but it has broken link.

Thank you.

Comment: You can ask for papers behind paywalls at scholar.reddit.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One should use official sources. The  DOI is [dx.doi.org/10.1080/00927877708822224](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/00927877708822224). I shall not discuss debatable [alternatives](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/68236/how-does-libgen-scihub-affect-researchers-research-and-publishing-process/68243#68243https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/68236/how-does-libgen-scihub-affect-researchers-research-and-publishing-process/68243#68243).

Comment: Thank you man, for your  help

Comment: @Camilo Acevedo I would deny personal implication :)